# Smartgit always asking for password credentials

Tags: php, git, bitbucket

I am using bitbucket for my project and using SmartGit 17.0.4 for pull and pull to my repository. Every time it asks to enter the username and password. I searched it, but didnt get any solution. Anyone knows?

Here is the screenshot of popup . http://prntscr.com/fd91v7

Comment: [this](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage) might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

SmartGit should use the Windows Credential Manager to cache your password.
See "[Using the Git credentials manager](http://www.syntevo.com/doc/display/SG/Using+the+Git+credentials+manager)".
Check the output of:

```
git config credential.helper
```

But, there is an issue reporting that password gets deleted from the credential manager: [issue 58](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/issues/58#issuecomment-294373570).

> I have a situation with SmartGit and Git Credential Manager for Windows:
>
> After entering the password, I can confirm that it is added to the Credential Manager.
> However, even after using the `setx GCM_PRESERVE_CREDS true` (and restarting SmartGit and the Credential Manager service), the credentials still get removed after some period of time (short, around 15 minutes), and the manager pops up again.

This bug is still in progress.

Comment: `git config credential.helper` doesn't do anything anymore?

Comment: @endolith It does. But if it returns nothing, that means HTTPS credentials are *not* cached. A `git config --global credential.helper manager` (on Windows) should help.